# How to get unspents using the private key of the bip84 wallet

Tags: python, python-bitcoinlib

Maybe my question is stupid, but I really can't figure
out why when I use the bip44 private key, it works, but if it's bip84, it doesn't

```python
from bit import PrivateKey, Key
import bitcoinlib
my_key = PrivateKey('Private key here')
tx = my_key.send([(wallet, money, 'btc')], unspents=my_key.get_unspent, fee=10)
    print(tx)
```

I realized that this is because my_key is not of the correct format, and for example, if I try to get_balance from my my_key, it returns the value 0. So, how to do it correctly?